# Is it Possible to Perform Addition in a Regex?

Tags: asp.net, regex

Assuming the placeholder $2 is populated with an integer, is it possible to increment it by 1?:

```
var strReplace = @"$2";
Regex.Replace(strInput, @"((.)*?)", strReplace);
```

Comment: If you are using Javascript then try the below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423107/use-regexp-to-match-a-parenthetical-number-then-increment-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a callback version of `Regex.Replace` with a `MatchEvaluator`, see examples at:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace

Here's an example ([ideone](http://ideone.com/dSK0V)):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static string AddOne(string s)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(s, @"\d+", (match) =>
        {
            long num = 0;
            long.TryParse(match.ToString(), out num);
            return (num + 1).ToString();
        });
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AddOne("hello 123!"));
        Console.WriteLine(AddOne("bai bai 11"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hello 124!
bai bai 12
```

Answer (score 2):

In standard (CS theoretic) regular expressions, it is impossible with a regular expression.

However, Perl and such have extensions to Regular Expressions, which has implications for their behaviour, and I am not familiar enough with them to definitely say that the extended regexes will not do it, but I'm fairly sure that this behaviour is not possible with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with a standard regular expression but you can if you write a custom MatchEvaluator.

```
string str = "Today I have answered 0 questions on StackOverlow.";
string pattern = @"\w*?(\d)";
var result = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, 
                   m => (int.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value)+1).ToString() );
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

> Today I have answered 1 questions on StackOverlow.